# Warning on Heroku with JRuby and Puma: "The signal USR1 is in use by the JVM and will not work correctly on this platform"

Tags: heroku, jvm, jruby, jrubyonrails, puma

Basically, as the title says, logs show the following warning on every restart:

```
2015-03-30T13:59:14.504047+00:00 app[web.2]: The signal USR1 is in use by the JVM and will not work correctly on this platform
```

When I tried to google this up only results I got was different deployment errors and people wrongly assuming the warning is the result, but no mention of the warning itself.

Does anybody know what this means and what are the implications? Is there a way to resolve it and should it even be resolved?

We are using JRuby 1.7.16 in 1.9.3 mode & Rails 4.1.1 but the warning has been happening to people using other versions of Rails too

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just a warning that you can ignore. I was getting the [same message with guard-jruby-rspec](https://github.com/jkutner/guard-jruby-rspec#how-to-use-on-demand-mode) on my local machine. I'm pretty sure it turned out to be something about how Bundler launches a secondary process and then tries to signal it. There is a [Puma issue to corroborate this](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/407).

Are you running the `puma` command with `bundle exec`? I think you can safely remove this on Heroku because there will only be one puma gem installed the slug.

Comment: The referenced issue does not corroborate the problem.  The referenced issue is about puma failing to start due to port contention.